# How to add a class with focus and click but not have the function run twice?

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to jQuery and teaching my self. Below you will see the code I am working on and an included JSFiddle.

What I am looking to do is add a class when I focus on an input/select and also have the class added when I click on the parent div. I basically have it working but in 2 separate functions.

**Issues:**

1. When I click on the input it adds the class but then when I click on the parent div it runs the other function and vice versa.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Combine everything into one function.
2. Say something like if class exists do not run other function.

Please explain the code so I can learn from this. If you do not have a solution any hints or direction would also be helpful. Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/q90tue8L/

***HTML***

```
<div class="panel">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>

<div class="panel">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>

<div class="panel">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.panel{
    padding:15px;
    background:grey;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

.panel-primary{
    margin:0 15px 0 15px;
    background:blue;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

***jQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.panel').click(function () {
        $('.panel').removeClass('panel-primary');
        $(this).addClass('panel-primary');
    });

    $('input, select').bind('focus blur', function () {
        $(this).closest(".panel").toggleClass('panel-primary');
    });

});
```

Comment: Which function is running twice? Your issues are not clear to me.

Comment: So go to the JSFiddle and click the first input then click the parent div or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$('input, select').bind('focus blur', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.panel').removeClass('panel-primary');
    $(this).closest(".panel").addClass('panel-primary');
});
```

for your second function.

With [.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) you prevent the click event to "bubble" up the DOM. So it now never reaches the parent div to trigger your first function.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nLgqhqwc/)**

Comment: Wow quick and easy love it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if there is another way to do it like combining the 2 functions into one?

Comment: @user262430 No. Both functions serve 2 different purposes. By the way, you dont have any `select` elements in your HTML. You should remove that from your jQuery code.

Comment: @user262430 [This](http://jsfiddle.net/q44o5w1v/) would be a possibilty, but I wouldn't recommend this. I don't know if there could be some unwanted side-effects

Comment: @RahulDesai Thanks! appreciate the help and the explanation.